# Ubuntu 18.04 theme/interface changed

Tags: 18.04, themes, desktop-environments, evolution

I accidentally removed  `evolution-data-server` from my Ubuntu 18.04 and then I installed again, however after restarting theme is totally changed.

[image: screenshot]

How can I go back to default (new 18.04) theme ?

I was on Ubuntu 16 > 17 > 18 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you've logged into a Unity session somehow, you need to log into a (default) GNOME session.

To do that when you boot your system and get to the GDM login screen you should find a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the sign in button. If you click on the cogwheel you should find an *Ubuntu* (and *Ubuntu on Wayland*) option. Select it and log in.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! How do i make sure I will always login to same?
I have not logged out so not sure what will happen next time.

Comment: @rohitrk89 GDM greeter should remember your login session preference in a normal circumstance.